# Angular2 ngOnInit Not firing

Tags: angular

I'm having trouble getting `ngOnInit` to fire after using `router.navigate` to go to a component. [Here are the files in a gist](https://gist.github.com/pjlamb12/9fa125c27d03c176ee33c7672033ceb4) that relate to my issue. In there I have the code for the a custom router outlet that I made that checks to see if a person is logged in or not. It works great; if they're logged in it sends them to the `dashboard` component. If they aren't, it sends them to the `home` component. The only problem is that when it sends them to the `dashboard` component, the `ngOnInit` function in the `dashboard` component isn't fired. Therefore, a section of the page I want to show/hide based on data that comes back from a service is hidden until I do a refresh.

I've had to use `NgZone` in a couple spots, and using that here hasn't helped any. I know that the `ngOnInit` function isn't run because putting a `console.log` in the function never gets called and thus doesn't print out.

Is there something that is keeping `ngOnInit` from running when using `router.navigate`?

Answer (score 1):

Might be https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8109#issuecomment-211450358

> Try using the Promise without importing it from es6-promise. If you include a module that provides a promise that hasn't been patched by zone.js, it will not trigger change detection which would explain why the lifecycle hooks aren't being called.

Or https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6867

> Lifecycle hooks not firing in IE 11.0.9600.18163